group items into maximimum number of groups
I have a set of items, each with numeric weight. how can I group the items in groups, such as each group has a weight of at least X, while maximizing the number of groups?

Found out it is a known (NP-hard) problem:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_covering_problem
